# I want to use a data listener in an unity app that when ever their is changes in the server an notification is sent to the user

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server, triggers, event-listener

i want to add a data listener to my unity app that when ever their is change in the server database the data listener in the unity can know from a  notification through a trigger implemented in server.

Comment: This is what you want, but what have you done so far, where is the problem you are facing ? Could you share a bit more, actually, the information you provide is not enough to have a solution for you.

Comment: Okay soo it is like this, we have an order panel in our,  when ever an new order is placed the order should be display in the order panel. Meaning that when a new order entry has been inserted in the database table, That entry needs to be displayed in the unity app. I was trying to add a trigger in the table, so that i can now when a new entry has been inserted, but i dont know how to add a data listener or http listener in unity to get the data from the server when it is updated.

Comment: You would need a websocket or SignalR or socket.io process. Client registers to server and server can broadcast info to listeners. Else, all clients would have to ping at regular interval to request if any changes.